# Error in Nested JSON in HIve

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, nested, hive-serde

I was trying to load this json data in hive

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
     "name": "Cake",
     "ppu": 0.55,
     "batters":
         {
             "batter":
                 [
                     { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                     { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

using DDL commands

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Downloads/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE format.json_serde (
  `id` string,
  `type` string,
  `name` string,
 `ppu` float,       
  batters` struct < `batter`:array < struct <`bid`:string, `btype`:string >>>,
  `topping`:array < struct<`tid`:int, `ttype`:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
```

is throwing me error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:11 cannot recognize input near ':' 'array' '<' in column type </b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You got typos
   **ttype`:string** should be **ttype:string**
   **battersstruct** should be **batters struct**
   **topping:array** should be **topping array**
2. JSON SerDe mapping is done by name.
   Your structs fields names should match the actual names, e.g. `id` and not `bid` or `tid`, otherwise you'll get NULL values for these fields.
3. There is already a JSON SerDe whicg is part of the Hive installation.
   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe

---

```
create external table json_serde 
( 
    id      string
   ,type    string 
   ,name    string 
   ,ppu     float
   ,batters struct<batter:array<struct<id:string,type:string>>>
   ,topping array<struct<id:string,type:string>>
) 
row format serde 
'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from json_serde
;
```

---

```
+------+-------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  | type  | name |        ppu        |                                                                     batters                                                                      |                                                                                                                  topping                                                                                                                  |
+------+-------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.550000011920929 | {"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"1003","type":"Blueberry"},{"id":"1004","type":"Devil'sFood"}]} | [{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"PowderedSugar"},{"id":"5006","type":"ChocolatewithSprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}] |
+------+-------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, when i tried to query it returned folllowing error                   **Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@73304204; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@73304204; line: 1, column: 3]** Please let me know if you performed any formatting on the input data

Comment: Any JSON document should written in a single line. I'm not aware of any JSON SerDe that knows how to deal with multi-lines document.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i removed the semicolons near topping. Thanks

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE format.json_serde (

  `id` string,

  `type` string,

  `name` string,

  `ppu` float,

  `batters` struct<`batter`:array<
struct<`bid`:string, `btype`:string >>>,

`topping` array< struct<`tid`:string, `ttype`:string>>
)